# Calling previous activity method on dialog dismiss

Tags: android, android-activity, refresh, android-dialog

On click of a certain button in class `MainActivity`, a dialog is shown of some fragment `FragDialog`:

```
FragDialog cf = new FragDialog().newInstace();

cf.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

When a hardware back button is pressed OR when an activity `MainActivity` is focussed, the dialog is dismissed and I returned to the activity `MainActivity`.

The methods `onResume()`, `onAttach()` of activity `MainActivity` doesn't get called after dialog dismiss.

The idea is to refresh the activity `MainActivity` after the dialog dismiss in order to get the changed view according to fields selected in the dialog fragment `FragDialog`.

As mentioned in the doc [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html),

> ```
> // DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
> // in a transaction.  We also want to remove any currently showing
> // dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.
> ```

But adding `remove()` seems pointless as it doesn't getting called, even dialog is dismissing without it.

I wondered that if this will get called, then I can start the activity `MainActivity` again to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while you call dialog you are not loosing contrxt of activity, it is not going in inactive state. All you need just make an event to activity when your dialog is closed, it is quite easy if you cancel it by button. Then you just munnually change your View.

Here is nice article about Dialogs
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: I can make an event to activity when my dialog is closed but I have no idea that where it is getting closed so as to trigger the activity. I haven't called `remove()` to close it but it is closing. If I use `remove()`, it doesn't work.

Comment: it is simple) just override onDestroy() or onPause() for your fragment, make sure it will send event to your activity

Comment: I haven't thought calling `onDestroy()` of fragment. Rather I keep tried methods of activity to get called. Thanks!